# In Kubuntu Arabic keyboard layout does not has right alt key

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, keyboard-layout, arabic

The following screen shot explain the issue well, in which there is no key assigned for the right alt key or alt gr. This situation cause a problem with keyboard layout switching when the current active layout is set to Arabic I could not use right alt + shift in order to switch to English, but in English layout it works fine. I have tried all Arabic variants but without success, all of its previews missing the right alt. 
[image]

[image]

### Update

3rd level is not set to right alt and the issue is still the same. There is no right alt key defined in the Arabic layout!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's because those keyboard layouts use <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> / <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as a modifier key to access 3:rd and 4:th level symbols. You have two options:

1. Use <kbd>Left Alt</kbd> when switching layout.
2. Pick some other key as the level3 modifier key, so <kbd>Right Alt</kbd> can be used in the same way as <kbd>Left Alt</kbd>.

Comment: The problem is still the same. Checkout the update. The Arabic layout does not has a right alt.

Comment: @SaidbakR: I installed the Arabic layout and can't reproduce the issue you are having. Possibly you have some conflicting setting which affects the <Right Alt> key behavior.

Comment: I have tried all Arabic layouts variants, but the right alt is absent in everyone.

Comment: @SaidbakR: Sounds weird. I suppose you need help from someone who is more familiar with KDE than I am. (I tested on standard Ubuntu.)